# Why does NumPy ndarray.shape give (), however numpy ndarray.tofile writes data to file

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

i have a .npz file by a former co-worker and need to make heads and tails of it. Sad to say I am fresh one to Python and am currently stumped. First thing i tried, is to load the file into Python with

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.load("abc.npz")
```

Now I know, that there is a 'records' object in the .npz so i go

```
>>> recdata = data['records'];
```

As I didn't know what to make of the data yet, so I went

```
>>> recdata.shape
()
```

and

```
>>> recdata.dtype
dtype('O')
```

to see the shape, but there is nothing... However,

```
>>> recdata.tofile('data.out',",")
```

gives me a human-readable file with some data, an example

```
    {'30': {'caseinfo': {'nerve01 left': 2512, 'nerve02 right': 1824, 
'nerve02 left': 2458, 'nerve03 left': 8585, 'nerve01 right': 2206, 'nerve03 right': 4588}, 
'data': {'ps': array([  422,    39,    37,    35,    34,    36,    38,    39,    39,
```

...

```
468,   461,   449,   432,   414,   408,   410,   408], dtype=int16), 'pout': array([-28, -12, -10, ...,   7,   0,   7], dtype=int16), 
'Q': array([ 2885,  2933,  2933,  2934,  2933,  2933,  2933,  2933,  2936,
    2941,  2953,  2970,  3021,  3095,  3207,  3368,  3525,  3671,
```

... and so forth. Can someone help me understand was has been done here? I am guessing this not one, but several arrays. Or are this all separate dimensions save and named?

Comment: dtype gives me `dtype('O')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dtype` of `'O'` (or equivalently `object`) is just *a Python object*.

You have a zero-dimensional, single-valued array of a Python dictionary:

```
numpy.array({}, dtype=object)
#>>> array({}, dtype=object)

numpy.array({}, dtype=object).shape
#>>> ()
```

And

```
numpy.array({}, dtype=object).tofile("/tmp/data.out", ",")
```

just gives a file containing "`{}`", as you would expect.